# Upgrading to latest stable Mono

Tags: packaging, mono

Mono 2.8 was recently released boasting a couple of large performance improvements. It's far too late for it to make it into Maverick and I'm fairly inpatient.

I don't use Mono for anything mission-critical (*just* playing music and sorting photos) and if it breaks everything related to Mono, I can probably either live with it or fix it. I'm aware of how much I stand to lose if I mess things up.

So with that acknowledged, does anybody here know how to build Mono in a way where it could be dropped in to replace the current Mono (2.6.7)? By this I mean ideally mirroring the packages that Ubuntu uses so that if the worse does happen, I can just downgrade the packages.

Or is there a PPA that does all this for me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download and install the [mono-parallel 2.10 deb package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mono-parallel/files/mono-2.10.1-parallel-environment.deb/download).

After installing the deb file paste this in the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)

```
source mono-2.10-environment
```

After this your terminal will look like

> [mono] /var/dev/mono @

[Source](http://blog.fusonic.net/2010/10/mono-2-8-parallel-environment-debianubuntu-package/)

Comment: Great late addition. Have some points.

Comment: Great gun's WAYYYYYYY easier than trying to get the compile from source one working, I've had 4 attempts so far now, all result in "You have a PARTIALLY INSTALLED.... IN /OPT/MONO...", small problem though.  The link given here is 64bit AMD only, anyone know if there is a i386 build (The server I'm trying to get this on is not an x64)

Answer (score 8):

Mono 2.8 is not available in a PPA. But someone made a [script to automatically download, compile and install Mono 2.8 from source](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/10/mono-2-8-install-script-for-ubuntu-fedora/). That makes it a little bit easier.

Answer (score 7):

The place to go for a mono PPA is http://badgerports.org/ unfortunately it could be months before it will have mono 2.8

Novell do not believe it is their responsibility to provide mono packages for ubuntu so the effort has to come from the community.

Jo Shields maintains both the official packages and the badgerports PPA. He said it could be months before mono 2.8 is available via his PPA.

So your only option at this stage is to build from source. Which is not for the faint hearted.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](http://au.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9992451), you can just use a different prefix:

```
--prefix=/opt/mono28
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the latest Mono version by using the VMware image provided at: [Mono Downloads Page](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're command line savy, you can compile it from source, using sudo make checkinstall instead of sudo make install, to get debs that you can downgrade later (you'll have a load of debs to downgrade though, *YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED*!!!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the script has just been updated to [install Mono 2.10 on Fedora and Ubuntu](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/02/mono-2-10-install-script-for-ubuntu-fedora/). The scripts themselves are on [GitHub](https://github.com/nathanb/iws-snippets/tree/master/mono-install-scripts).

Answer (score 0):

There is a ppa.`ppa:gezakovacs/sandbox` contains mono 2.10 packages, with a big disclaimer at the top. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Same author as the link Tom Opgenorth provided, but updated for mono 2.10.1

https://github.com/nathanb/iws-snippets/raw/master/mono-install-scripts/ubuntu/update_mono-2.10-to-mono-2.10.1.sh

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...