# Upgrading Mono on lucid? getting "version 2.4 (tarball Fri Oct 2 12:47:18 CEST 2009)"

Tags: 10.04, server, upgrade, mono

im having some issues when trying to upgrade Mono

i have added to the sources.list
deb http://badgerports.org lucid main

tryed upgrade, seemd to runed fine, but i get

```
mono -V

Mono JIT compiler version 2.4 (tarball Fri Oct  2 12:47:18 CEST 2009)
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
```

and when doing again, i says already newest version.

```
# apt-get install mono-runtime mono-2.0-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
mono-runtime is already the newest version.
mono-2.0-devel is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-rpm rpm python-urlgrabber
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any one got a sugestion on how to get this fixed?

I have tryed

```
apt-get purge mono-runtime mono-2.0-devel
```

and done a reinstall but still same version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wondering why it's not upgrading to 2.8 the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5304/upgrading-to-mono-2-8) has your answer.