# where can I get Mono 2.10 for Maverick and Natty?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, package-management, development, mono

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading to latest stable Mono](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5304/upgrading-to-latest-stable-mono)

Hi, I want to use Mono for some projects, but in Ubuntu (or Debian in general) is just 2.6.7 avalible. And I could not find any packages or PPAs.

I tried to compile it myself, but I failed.

Where can I get the current Mono 2.10 Version for Ubuntu Maverick and Natty? http://badgerports.org/ only supports Lucid and Hardy and is not up to date

Comment: You should elaborate on why you failed to compile it from source as that is going to be the only way to get it if there is no PPA for it.

Comment: Closing this as duplicate of an old question of mine. Unfortunately everything appears the same: badgerports only supports LTS releases and even then, they're painfully slow to update. Building it yourself still appears to be the only route to success. The accepted answer does help with that to some degree.

Comment: I found this question, but I didn't see that there was an answer for 2.10 too

Comment: Not your fault. When you saw it, it *was* aimed at 2.8 (2.8 was the latest when I asked) but I've opened it up to be more generic.